# IE7 is indenting text when it shouldn't be

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

*Moved the link because it no longer points to the site, and solution has been found*

I have some list elements that have a mysterious left padding/margin.

In Firefox, it displays as expected. But in IE7, there is a text indent or something forcing the inner text in about 4 spaces. See the example link above.

I have set `padding` to 0, `margin` to 0 (though it shouldn't be this as clearly the border goes around the element containing the gap), `text-indent` to 0, and `text-align: left`.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: FYI, this appears normal in IE8.  Sorry I don't have an answer though!

Comment: Did you get the same results in compatibility mode... i.e. the indent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your style.css file you set the LIST-STYLE-POSITION to inside.  This is causing your issue in IE.

```
#content-body UL {
    LIST-STYLE-POSITION: inside; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: disc
}
```

You can either remove that element, or you can add a style to your .events UL

```
.events UL {
    ...
    LIST-STYLE-POSITION: outside! important;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post this same answer after debugging! Good catch.

Comment: Ah of course... I hate implementing other people's CSS, like the calendar's!